# How can I fade in and out between cameras during animation?

Tags: animation, camera

I have a scene with 3 cameras pointing to specific angles on an evolving object.  During the evolution of the  object, I need to switch camera so that the object is still framed correctly.  The cameras are moving as well.
I have used markers but the  switching is too brutal.  I would like to fade out the current camera and fade in the new one..  I know that if I shoot separate sequences I can do that in post prod but doing it  during animation allow me to position the motion of the camera more efficiently..  Is there a way to-do that ?  I use the latest release of Blender.

Answer (score 10):

What Todd says does work, but it is not the best way of doing things.

Go to the *Video Editing* Screen Layout. Add a *Scene* strip, and then add the same Scene strip again so you have the two scenes on top of each other. In the *properties panel* (key <kbd>N</kbd> with the cursor inside the VSE portion of your screen), go to the Scene part and to the *Camera Override*. Select one camera in the first *Scene* strip, and the second camera in the second *Scene* strip. The `*Scene* strips will now have the added text of the names of the cameras along their length.

Next, add a *Cam Multicam* *Effect Strip*. Make sure it is directly on top of the two *Scene* strips. Click the 1 button to select the camera notated by the bottom *Scene* strip, or 2 to select the camera notated by the top *Scene* strip. Then move your cursor to where you want the fade to begin  and select 1 or 2, whichever you didn't select the first time. It will cut the strip into two parts.

Now move the first half of the *Cam Multicam* strip up to channel 4. Drag the right arrow of the top *Cam Multicam* strip to the frame where you want the fade to end.

Select the first strip, and then the second strip, and then key <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>A</kbd> and add a *Gamma Cross* *Effect Strip*. Your finished setup should look like this and provide the same result as Todd's.

[image]

Further research: [Multicam selector documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/video_editing/sequencer/strips/effects/multicam.html).

Comment: Hey this is great! I didn't know about the Multicam feature in the VSE. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: Very cool!  I really like the way you do it..  Thanks for your help and great solution..  It gives me also more usages beyond the fading process..  Great!

Comment: @YvesBodson If this answer helped you, you should consider accepting it by selecting the checkmark in its upper, left-hand corner. It would help me greatly and make me very happy. If there is something else that I can add, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to directly switch the active camera AND manage a transparency crossfade between the 2 cameras directly from a single scene.

What you can do is duplicate your scene by creating a second linked scene. Make Camera 2 active in the new scene. Then you can switch to the Video Sequence Editor and bring in a Scene strip for each of your 2 scenes. Now it's easy to cross fade the 2 camera views because it's just a like a video edit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: yeah cool!  Both answers are great.. did not think about cross fading two scenes strips..  Thanks for the solution.